# ActivityViewController Popup not on Top of the Screen

Tags: swift, popup, uiactivityviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I have a share button to share a screenshot of my screen. Although I implemented a extension to get the rootViewController, the popup of my ActivityViewController is still behind the window from which I want to share the screenshot [see image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKj3h.jpg). I already tried to load my handleDismiss() function inside the handleShare(), but without success so far. Maybe someone can get me on the right track, what is going on here.

Thank you very much in advance.

[Short gif of my Statistic View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUdiW.gif)

```
import UIKit

class GameStatistics: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let blackView = UIView()

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cv
    }()

    let cellId = "cellId"
    let sectionHeader = "sectionHeader"
    let sectionFooter = "sectionFooter"

    //
    //
    //

    func showStatistics() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            window.addSubview(collectionView)

            // Dynamic Height of Collection View
            let value: CGFloat = CGFloat(statistics.count)
            let height: CGFloat = value * cellHeight + (value - 1) * cellSpacing + headerHeight + footerHeight
            let y = window.frame.height - height

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.blackView.alpha = 1
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func handleDismiss() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return statistics.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! GameStatisticCell

        cell.statistic = statistics[indexPath.item]

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        //dump(statistics)
        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch  kind {

            case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
                let supplementaryView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: sectionHeader, for: indexPath)

                return supplementaryView
            case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
                let supplementaryView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: sectionFooter, for: indexPath)

                return supplementaryView
            default:
                fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: headerHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: footerHeight)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.register(GameStatisticCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.register(GameStatisticHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: sectionHeader)
        collectionView.register(GameStatisticFooter.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: sectionFooter)
    }

    func handleShare() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let size = CGSize(width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            window.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image!], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
 }
```

**Extension**

```
extension UIApplication {

    static var topViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.visibleViewController
    }
}

extension UIViewController {

    var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigationController.topViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController {
            return presentedViewController.visibleViewController
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add activity controller on the window because you have added it on controller and statistics view added on window thats why actovity controller behind the Statistics

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary: Can you be a little more precise? Sorry, but I am still a beginner in Swift programming. I changed the last line to: window.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) I guess this is not, what you have suggested, since it is not working as well.

Comment: Pajak Remove collection view from window and add it on topview

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary: I added a short gif, where you can see, that my statistic collection view isn't part of my top view. It's more a popup by itself. I either want to dismiss the floating in statistic window after pressing the share button, or force the activity controller window to be on top of it. So I am not sure what you mean by moving the collection view to the top view?